# How to create a RESTFul Controller Action in ASP.NET MVC 3.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have created an Action in my Home Controller which accepts a text:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       public string DisplayText(string text)
        {
            return text;
        }
    }
```

I can call this Action, using the below url by passing the text parameter as a query string:

```
http://localhost:4574/Home/DisplayText?text=some text
```

However, I'd like to be able to call this using the below style:

```
http://localhost:4574/Home/DisplayText/some text
```

Therefore without specifying the parameter name ("text");

**How would that be possible?**

Another example to explain it more clearly is as below

```
public string Add(string a, string b)
        {
            return (int.Parse(a) + int.Parse(b)).ToString();
        }
```

I can call it using:

```
http://localhost:4574/Home/Add?a=2&b=3
```

but how to call it in a RESTFul way? e.g. (`http://localhost:4574/Home/Add/2/3`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyRoute",
    "{controller}/{action}/{a}/{b}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Add" },
    // it's always a good idea to define route constraints
    // in this case we are constraining the a and b parameters to numbers only
    new { a = @"\d+", b = @"\d+" } 
);
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Add(int a, int b)
{
    return Content(string.Format("The result of {0}+{1}={2}", a, b, a + b));
}
```

Comment: you beat me to it :). However, he should consider when it really should be part of the url or when it should be a parameter.

Comment: @TomasJansson, yes, that's an important design choice to make.

Comment: @TomasJansson, several answers are encouraged. Your could contain the query-vs-resource tips. :)

Comment: @bzlm, that's more of a sidnote. Except from that my answer was exactly the same so I deleted it. The sidnote is here now on the answer with the most votes which make it easier to find.

Comment: thanks. couple of questions 1) why would you rather returning ActionResult rather than string? 2) putting route constraints will constraint all the routes in the application so that doesn't seem to be a good idea since some Actions may have different data types e.g. string, etc. right? so how would you write it without constraint?

Comment: @TomasJansson, the question isn't about routing, it's about RESTfulness in general, and names of resources in particular. Also, by second-guessing the community-interaction-based QA mechanism, you're not really letting it bloom to its fullest.

Comment: The Add parameter is fixed but the DisplayText not. I added this: routes.MapRoute("mapRouteToSupport1InputParameter", "{controller}/{action}/{a}");

Comment: @William, 1) By convention all controller actions return an ActionResult - makes it easier to unit test 2) No, it will constrain only this route. You could still have the default route after it.